# Ajax on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am a beginner to ruby on rails.But i am quite comfortable with php, Jquery. But i am not able to get the picture behind the screen in ajax in rails.
Can anybody suggest me a good book for ajax in rails or some good tutorials.
Right now i am working on Agile Web Development with Rails book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Railscasts are always a good place to start.

In particular:
[RailsCast #136 - jQuery](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery) covers basics of using jquery for ajax in rails. Since you are already familiar with jquery... [Same thing in text format - AsciiCast](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/136-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

[Ruby on Rails Tutorial
Learn Rails by Example
Michael Hartl](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning?version=2.3#top)
If you need to get basic idea about AJAX with rails I strongly recommend this online tutorial It will give more basic understand about the rails.